# What does this Chinese reporter say about APEC and Putin?

Tags: mandarin

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iW4ZzxuSXbc

I can sort of follow along but there are some words/phrases I'm not clear on.  Here's what I can gather:

今天外场的演出分为...展室...和焰火三个部分, 而负责这场表演的团队呢，完全是2008年北京奥运会开幕式的导源的团队。  而在等待的过程当中，各个...的领导人在形势的交谈...看到葡京总统特...外套披在彭丽媛的身上。

If anybody could help, I'd surely appreciate it.

Cheers,
Rachel

Answer (score 2):

**光艺展示**，**巨型的视频网幕**，和焰火三个部分。

光艺展示: Display of light effects

巨型的视频网幕: Giant video display,

各个**经济体**的领导人在**饶有兴致地**交谈，刚才我们看到普京总统**特地地把一件**外套披在了彭丽媛的身上。

经济体: Economic entity

饶有兴致: With quite some interest

特地：Specially, with the quality of caring and thoughtfulness.

Comment: Though it looks weird, as an adverb, 特地**地**把一件 is the very correct form.

Comment: @Stan OK. I knew what is correct but I did that intentionally.  To me the structural strangeness beats grammatical purity. Also there are efforts to unify some usage of 地 and 的 in 1980s (http://wenku.baidu.com/view/fdfbeb5e804d2b160b4ec0d0.html ). It was never really accepted among the learned, but I personally liked the idea. :)

Comment: I love that idea too -- and I also had guessed you did it by intention :) The problem was about consistency: because "饶有兴致地" had been carefully marked as an adverb by 地, if 特地 wasn't treated in the same way, one would wonder if you created a new grammar rule like "when we encounter ***structural strangeness***, we need to do something" Then the learner might further be curious about the definition of "structural strangeness". In my opinion, that's no easier than just following the "adj的/adv地/complement得" pattern.

Comment: @Stan Yes indeed. May I add one: When in doubt, use 的. NO! Don't listen to me..